# distinguish inner class modifiers in ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a way in `ruby` to distinguish between static, public and private inner class ?
I am thinking about `java` or other `OOP` language which provides this kind of stuffs

```
public class Outer {
    ....
    public/private (static) class Inner {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have inner classes, therefore it obviously doesn't have access modifiers for them.

You *can*, however, simulate inner classes using methods (and methods can be made `private`):

```
class Outer
  private def Inner
    @__inner_class__ ||= Class.new do
      …
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: sorry, you can nest a class within a class, no ?

Comment: No, you can't. First off, nested classes are not about nesting classes in classes, they are about nesting classes in objects. You can nest class definitions in Ruby, but that won't make the class nested, it will only assign the class to a constant within the outer class. But there Im is no relationship between the two classes, nesting or otherwise.

Comment: ok you mean putting some class inside a class is almost make it static with the outer class as a DSL reference ?

Answer (score -3):

It does not map 1:1 to java.

You can however use namespacing.

```
class Outer
  class Inner

# And scope to them via Outer::Inner
# or you could use Outer as module; then you can use
#   include Outer
# to include it into your other code.
```

Inside them you can freely use private or public or protected (but I don't know many who use protected).

This link here gives a nice intro-read:

http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/09/07/protected-methods-and-ruby-2-0.html

Remember: you can use something like this:

```
class Foo

  def initialize
  end
  private # from this point on, all methods defined will default to be private

  def foo
  end
```

Comment: -1. The question is not about public or private methods, it is about public or private *classes*, which Ruby doesn't have.

Comment: Let the thread starter consider whether my reply to him is useful or not - but thank you so much for downvoting me whereas I upvoted your reply. Talk about fairness huh? "You last voted on this answer 7 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Comment: The StackOverflow voting system is not about fairness, it is about quality. You upvoted my answer because it is correct, I downvoted yours because it is incorrect. I even took the time to explain to you *why* your answer is incorrect, which I'm not obliged to.